# How to store date field as moment.js objects in Backbone.Model?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, momentjs

I have Backbone.Model like the following:

```
{
   id: '1',
   startTime: 'Sun May 04 2014 13:00:00 GMT+0400 (MSK)',
   endTime: 'Sun May 04 2014 13:29:59 GMT+0400 (MSK)',
}
```

At now I store startTime and endTime as strings in my database but on client side I want to store them as [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) objects for handy working with them.

How could I store them as momment.js in my Backbone.Model to be possible to get and set as moment.js objects but store on server side as pure strings?

Should I use some Backbone extension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this?

```
yourModel.set('startTime', moment("Dec 25, 1995"));
```

You can convert after fetch like this,

```
yourModel.parse = function(response) {
    response.startTime = moment(response.startTime);
    return response;    
};
```

Comment: How to make it automatically? Especially when I fetch collection of my models. myCollection.fetch()

Comment: In your model's parse function, you can convert it easily

Comment: Hmm. Very interesting, I need to try it out.